# maximizing $\angle APB$ in 3-D space

Tags: vectors, 3d

> Given $A(0,0,1),B(2,1,2)$ be rwo points in a 3_D space and $P(a,b),a,b>0$ be a point on the xy plane such that  $\angle APB$ is maximum then find $a,b$,(A,P,B are non collenear)

This question was given in a mock exam I was writing.
It is clear that the plane passing through $A,P,B$ will be perpendicular to the $x-y$ plane.So after some work we can conclude the plane is $x-2y=0$ thus $a=2b$.Also the cosine of the angle $<APB$ is

$$\cos (\angle APB)=\frac{2b(2b-2)+b(b-1)+2}{\sqrt{(5b^2+1)(5{(b^2-2b+1)+4)}}}=L$$  so it remains to minimize $L$.But that will be very tedious task especially in an entrance exam mock test.So what is the best way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

If you draw a circumcircle of $ABP$ with the centre $O$, one can see that $\angle APB$ is maximal when $OP\perp xy$.

[image]

If $P$ has coordinates $(2y,y,0)$, then $O$ has coordinates $(2y,y,z)$ and we can write $AO^2=OP^2$ and $BO^2=OP^2$:

$$4y^2+y^2+(z-1)^2 = z^2, \\ 4(y-1)^2+(y-1)^2+(z-2)^2=z^2$$

It's easy to eliminate $z$, solve a quadratic equation on $y$ and choose the root $0<y<1$.

Comment: would you please clarify that why you considerd only circle passing through those points to maximise the angle .Where does that intuation come from?

Comment: If segment $AB$ is seen from $P$ with angle $\angle APB = \alpha$, then from every point $X$ inside the circle segment $APB$, it will be seen with greater angle $\angle AXB > \alpha$. Thus, if circle $APB$ crosses the plane, there is a point with a greater angle on the intersection of disk with a plane. If the intersection contains only one point, the circle is touching the plane.

Answer (score 0):

Hints :

- P will lie on the projection of line through AB on the x-y plane.

> $(x=2y,z=0)$

- P would be equidistant from A and B (so PAB is an isosceles triangle).