# Angle optimisation problem in 3 dimensions.

Tags: optimization, triangles, 3d, angle

I came across this question in test.

> Given $A(0,0,1), B(2,1,2)$ be two points in 3-D space also P($\alpha ,\beta$) ($\alpha>0 ,\beta>0$) be a point on the xy-plane
> such that $\angle APB$ is maximum, then find $\alpha,\beta$

I tried ploting those points roughly in space and then tried to express the angle in terms of $\alpha,\beta$ but since its 3-D I am finding it hard to imagine there position.also the equations i got are too complicated (probably wrong) so i am not mentioning them here.

I wanted to know if there is a simplier method.

Welcome in advance!!

REGARDS!

Comment: I'm sorry. My approach couldn't work. The answer is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4168132/815585) using a much more elegant method

Comment: Sorry for wasting your time

Comment: @FShrike Its ok thanks a lot that you tried to help